# Constrain dragging of a marker to a polyline in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

Is there a way to constrain a marker so that when it is dragged, it moves along a given polyline in Leaflet JS?

In my page I have route that is presented as a Polyline and a Marker.  I want to be able to drag the marker along the line to be able to display information about that part of the route.

Looking at the documentation here, it is not clear how I would go about that:

https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#marker

Note, I am using leaflet by means of [vue2leaflet](https://vue2-leaflet.netlify.com/), though a solution that works for standard leaflet JS would be okay.

The vue 'template':

```html
      <l-map
        class="leaftlet-map"
        :zoom="map.zoom"
        :center="map.center"
        @update:zoom="zoomUpdated"
        @update:center="centerUpdated"
        @update:bounds="boundsUpdated"
      >
        <l-tile-layer :url="map.url" :attribution="map.attribution" />
        <l-marker
          v-if="positionMarker"
          :lat-lng="positionMarker.center"
          draggable
          @move="markerMoved"
        />
        <l-polyline
          v-if="polyline.latlngs && polyline.latlngs.length > 0"
          :lat-lngs="polyline.latlngs"
          :color="polyline.color"
        />
      </l-map>
```

Comment: First https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html , then https://github.com/makinacorpus/Leaflet.Snap

Comment: The one issue I see with Leaflet.Snap is that it allows 'unsnapping' which isn't ideal. I did see `Leaflet.AnimatedMarker`, but that looks unmaintained. I'll take a look at `Leaflet.GeometryUtil` and see if there is anything there that could help.

Comment: What about adjusting `snapDistance` option?

Answer (score 2):

This is a quick hack just to test the concept. Since `img` element is draggable by itself, `L.divIcon` is used for draggable marker so that `draggable="false"` attribute could be set. For keeping marker glued to polyline, polyline method `closestLayerPoint` is used to locate closest point to mouse position on polyline.

CSS:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.leaflet-div-icon {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="map"></div>
<div style="display:none;">
  <img id="icon" draggable="false" src="lib/leaflet/1.6/images/marker-icon.png">
</div>
```

JS:

```
var osm = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: 'Map data &copy; OpenStreetMap contributors',
});

var map = L.map('map').addLayer(osm);

var path = L.polyline([[43, 1],[43, 1.5],[43.5, 2],[44, 3],[43.5, 4]], {
    color: 'red',
    opacity: 1.0
}).addTo(map);

map.fitBounds(path.getBounds());

var myIcon = L.divIcon({
  html: document.getElementById('icon'),
  iconSize: [25, 41],
  iconAnchor: [12.5, 41],
});

var myMarker = L.marker([43, 1], {icon: myIcon}).addTo(map);

myMarker.on({
  mousedown: function () {
    map.on('mousemove', function (e) {
      map.dragging.disable();
      var point = path.closestLayerPoint(map.latLngToLayerPoint(e.latlng))
      myMarker.setLatLng(map.layerPointToLatLng(point));
    });
  }
}); 
map.on('mouseup',function(e){
  map.removeEventListener('mousemove');
  map.dragging.enable();
});
```